# Derivative of the modified Bessel function of third kind with respect to its order in R

Tags: r, derivative

How can I find the derivative of the modified Bessel function of third kind ($K_{\nu}(x)$) with respect to its order ($\nu$)?  Specifically, how can I evaluate

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial K_{\nu}(x)}{\partial \nu}
\end{equation}

in R, where $\nu$ and $x$ are assumed real to be real.

R package [Bessel](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Bessel/index.html) evaluates Bessel functions for a variety of arguments ($x$) and order ($\nu$).  There is also R package [fAsianOptions](http://cran.at.rproject.org/web/packages/fAsianOptions/index.html) that evaluates the Bessel functions for integer order and has functions for evaluating

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial K_{\nu}(x)}{\partial x} \; (\text{note } x \text{ not } \nu).
\end{equation}

A related, but not similar, question is [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4019/derivate-bessel-function-with-respect-to-order).

The recurrence relation between the $\frac{\partial K_{\nu}(x)}{\partial \nu}$ and other Bessel function can be found [here](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.38).

Using [asymptotic expansions](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.41#ii)

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial K_{\nu}(x)}{\partial \nu} = K_{\nu}(x)\bigg[1 - \frac{1}{2\nu} - \log \big(\frac{ex}{2\nu} \big)\bigg].
\end{equation}

I was wondering if there are better approximations.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.38) can help? I find it pretty usefull.

Comment: Why not just compute a finite difference approximation?  Simple and fast.